# Update HTML title attribute on hover / async

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some rather expensive data to get for the content of many html "title" attributes on my webpage, so I want to load the data for this attribute only when the user requests it (on hover, for obvious reasons). I am able to set the title attribute fine on hover, but it does not appear correctly. Specifically, I must move the mouse pointer at least one pixel after the async call finishes before the text appears. I would like the text to appear as soon as the async call finishes (or at least, after the usual hover text delay if the async call finishes sooner)

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.thumbnail', function(){
    var self = $(this);

    setTimeout(function(){
        var titleStr = "yay, a new title";

        self.attr('title', titleStr)
      $('#status').text("title set!")
    }, 1000)    

});
```

(I cant find the runnable code button on this new question "wizard", so here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/76dk3snz/)

I have also tried running other events like .trigger('mousemove') or mouseleave and mouseenter, etc, but nothing seems to trigger the desired behavior.

(That is, I would like the text to show up without the user having to move the mouse again)

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly this is what you want. `document.title = 'My new Title here';`

Comment: I guess it depends on the browser because for me, the title appears without changing the pointer's position. I'm using MacOS Chrome version 71.

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome, you can set the title of the element *before* calling the expensive operation, and then the loading text will appear as a tooltip, and will be replaced with the real title once the response comes back:

```js
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.thumbnail', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  self.attr('title', 'Loading...')
  setTimeout(function() {
    var titleStr = "yay, a new title";
    self.prop('title', titleStr)
    $('#status').text("title set!")
  }, 1000)


});
```

```css
.thumbnail {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbnail">

</div>

<div id="status">

</div>
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to force the refresh of the `title` in Firefox, unfortunately - the mechanism is internal to the browser, and only affected by user-initiated mose events.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.   "Loading..." persists until the mouse moves, which is the original problem. Firefox

Comment: confirmed that this works on Chrome (Linux) ; on Firefox (Linux), the  "Loading..." persists even after moving the mouse. >.>

Comment: @Rboreal_Frippery Yep, for FF your only real option is to use the same method you're using in your question. Though, you might consider switching to a full-fledged tiny modal instead of an inflexible `title` attribute